# Create a list from a loop using each element of a list

Tags: python, list, loops, arraylist

I want to create a friends_list for each user ID in the usr list. This is what I have tried so far. I don't know how to call friends_list for each one or even all of them together in one list.

```
 def first_surface(friends):
     usr = ['298970145', '11922952', '17455195']

     for i in usr: 
    
         friends_list = []
    
         for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, user_id = usr).items(15):
             friends_list.append(user.id)

  return
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? it creates a list of the friends lists

```
 def first_surface(friends):
     usr = ['298970145', '11922952', '17455195']
     list_of_friends = []

     for i in usr:         
         friends_list = []        
         for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, user_id = usr).items(15):
             friends_list.append(user.id)
         list_of_friends.append(friends_list)

  return list_of_friends
```

If you want to know the friends list for the first user, it would simply be `list_of_friends[0]`

Comment: Thanks for replying, it wasn't what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have got what I wanted with the code below:

```
friends_list = []

usr_all = ['298970145', '11922952', '17455195'];

for usr in usr_all:

  for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, user_id = usr).items(15):
    friends_list.append(user.id)
```

However, I still don't know how to retrieve the friend_list for user 1 in the list for example.